# Some questions on multiple logistic regression

Tags: logistic, multiple-regression, binomial-distribution, sample-size, statistical-power

Let's say we have k binary (binomial) variables, and a sample size of n observations per variable, where each variable occurs (positive case) at a given frequency/probability f. We would like to check if there is a correlation between these variables by multiple logistic regression, so the null hypothesis assumes that they are all independent from each other (no correlation).

Some questions:

1. Does it matter which variable we pick as the dependent variable?  Or to put it another way, is there a way to do multiple logistic regression in a symmetrical manner, so that it *doesn't* matter which variable we pick as the dependent variable?
2. What test statistic should be used to measure the degree of correlation between these binary variables?  Is there a "symmetric" one, where it doesn't matter which variable we pick as the dependent variable?
3. What is the appropriate distribution (f, t, z, chi^2, etc.) for this test statistic, and how does the CDF depend on various parameters, such as n, k and f?  Is there a formula to define this?
4. What is the best way to calculate the minimum sample size n required to identify a "significant" correlation (p <= alpha) between these variables?  Is there a formula to define how are n, k, f and alpha linked to each other mathematically?  Are any other parameters involved in the formula, e.g., beta, R^2, etc.? Could the Wald test or likelihood-ratio test be used here?
5. And finally, is multiple regression (logistic or otherwise) really the right approach to test for a correlation between these binomial variables, or is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 1):

What you are probably looking for is [loglinear analysis](http://teaching.sociology.ul.ie/SSS/lugano/lugano.html). This is a very old-school technique that models a cross-tabulation. It does not have the concept of a dependent and independent variable, which is why it lost popularity, but there are special circumstances (like yours) where this is actually a bonus.

The measure of association used in this type of analysis is the odds ratio. You can use a likelihood ratio test to compare models with a model with all 1s for odds ratios (independence).

Comment: Thanks, Maarten, this sounds promising.  I'm particularly interested in understanding the power calculations for this case, if you know of any formulae (as per question 4)?

Comment: And maybe I should ask, is regression really the right approach to test for correlation between binomial variables, or is there a simpler way? (edit: I have added this to my original post).

Comment: With categorical variables the odds ratio is a more useful measure of association than the correlation. This automatically leads again to log-linear analysis.